# Emergency Stop. (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

Tags: errors

I'm trying to do my paper here in latex, without fully understanding it. 
I stumbled upon a problem in which is solvable if I clear the cache. But every time I Recompile it, the error comes up again.

The paper has grown into quite a long one now, and I don't know what is the cause.

Here is what the red area has shown me:

```
  Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5 strings out of 492990
 123 string characters out of 6132621
 54148 words of memory out of 5000000
 3663 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and this is the Raw Logs:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.7.12)  3 SEP 2017 18:35
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5 strings out of 492990
 123 string characters out of 6132621
 54148 words of memory out of 5000000
 3663 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Can someone direct me what is the keyword should I search for to solve this?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the log file?  Because it's running into the error almost immediately.  What's the first few lines of `main.tex`?

Comment: If the paper is long, try commenting out sections of it, or just put a `\end{document}` at 50% into the text. If the error vanishes, move the `\end{document}` to 75%; if it persists, move it to 25%. In this manner, isolate the offending bit of text and post it here as a MWE.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer the error message suggests that the document is short (very short:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you (a) do not have a file `main.tex` and (b) you called latex in batchmode so that no missing error file is given on the terminal.

If I do

```
 pdflatex -interaction=batchmode main.tex
```

Then the terminal just shows

```
$ pdflatex -interaction=batchmode main.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

But the log appears in TeX's default log file of `texput.log` and shows

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.7.3)  3 SEP 2017 20:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3 strings out of 492987
 99 string characters out of 6132658
 54148 words of memory out of 5000000
 3666 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```